# Unable to update the EntitySet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The following code:

```
sistema_log_openedPdfs entity = new sistema_log_openedPdfs();
entity.idUser = guid;
entity.path = fullAbsPath;
context.sistema_log_openedPdfs.Add(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this crazy exception:

`[UpdateException: Unable to update the EntitySet 'sistema_log_openedPdfs` 
`because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the` `<ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.]`

Lokking for help I could not find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you forget to make a primary key for `sistema_log_openedPdfs` ???

Comment: Yes, the primary key was not created. Thanks